# How to use SET XACT_ABORT ON the right way

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, try-catch, rollback, xact-abort

We have recently been parachuted to a new ETL project with very bad code.
I have in my hands a query with 700 rows and all sort of update.

I would like to debug it with `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` and the goal is to rollback everything if only one transaction fails.

But I find several way to archive it on StackOverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735683/i-am-using-the-transaction-in-sql-to-force-all-the-query-results-in-success-but):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY

-- Multiple sql statements goes here

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH
```

or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50235755/how-to-use-set-xact-abort-on-without-transaction):

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Multiple sql statements goes here

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
PRINT(ERROR_MESSAGE())
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

and none of these uses `SET XACT_ABORT ON;`.

I don't understand, is `SET XACT_ABORT ON` the same as using `BEGIN TRY BEGIN TRANSACTION`?

Can I just use:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

-- Multiple sql statements goes here
```

and get ridof all the:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY
```

?

And also, should I use `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and then `BEGIN TRY` or the other way around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not the same. It decides when errors are thrown.

You should always use `SET XACT_ABORT ON`, because it is more consistent; almost always, an error will stop execution and throw an error. Else, half things throw errors and the other half continue execution.

There is a great [article](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) about this whole subject on [Erland Sommarskog's site](https://www.sommarskog.se/), and if you go at [this point](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#classification) you will see a table which describes this strange behaviour. In conclusion, I recommend the [General Pattern for Error Handling](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpgeneralpattern), as it is very well documented as well as provide you the opportunity to tweak it according to its own documentation.

Comment: You are saying that XACT_ABORT ON will cause all errors to hit the CATCH block?

Comment: Not all, but more. Click the link "this point" of my answer to see a full list.

Comment: When SET XACT_ABORT is set to ON, then what purpose does the try/catch serve? Looking at the table you shared (from that link), when using TRY CATCH, for the CATCHABLE column it doesn't matter whether XACT_ABORT is ON or OFF.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `XACT_ABORT ON` there is no need to manually catch any errors, unless you are doing error logging. `XACT_ABORT` will cause all errors to doom the transaction and roll it back.

All you need is

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRAN;
--do stuff
COMMIT;
```

If there is only one statement then you don't even need `BEGIN TRAN;` and `COMMIT;`

Comment: I tested it @Charlieface and if I don't use `BEGIN TRAN;` and `COMMIT;` the table is created in my DB and data are inserted. this means that `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` needs `BEGIN TRAN;` and `COMMIT;`

Comment: You misunderstand: `BEGIN TRAN` `COMMIT` is needed if you want atomicity between two statements. `XACT_ABORT ON` means that an opened transaction is automatically aborted in event of an error. So *if* you use a transaction then you should use `XACT_ABORT`. But a single statement doesn't need a transaction, it has its own one anyway

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the resources @George Menoutis.

I post here my practical solution:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRY
      BEGIN TRANSACTION;


      -- Multiple sql statements goes here


      COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
      IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
      THROW;
END CATCH;
GO

SET XACT_ABORT OFF;
```

Comment: Thank you @GeorgeMenoutis, post it in your reply. Actuall I was having a problem with the code from Erland related to `RETURN 55555`

Comment: just throw @msg I guess

Comment: 1. Does `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` cause all errors to hit the catch block?

Comment: 2. Since you have set `SET XACT_ABORT ON;`, why are you using the try/catch? What purpose does try catch serve?

Comment: @variable, not sure.... but I see it in every example. I don't know if SET XACT_ABORT ON;
replaces BEGIN TRY. I think you have to use both